# How to run a servlet based project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, servlets

I have a servlet based project which uses JSF, I don't know how to configure and run it in IntelliJ IDEA. Hope you can guide me. Or are there any related instructions that can help me run it, hoping you all can guide me.

When I try it then I face the following error

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /Users/minhthuanluu/Documents/ViettelTelemor/Web/boc2_web/jsf-api-2.2.0.jar no main manifest attribute

Comment: Do you have the original source code? Was the project built on Maven or Gradle or some such?

Comment: JSP and JSF are different Java web application development technologies - which one are you trying to work with? Typically, applications developed with these technologies are packaged as WAR files and are deployed (to run) on a Java enabled web server or application server.

Comment: @BasilBourque I was used Maven to built it.

Comment: @prasad_ I think I'm using JSF

Comment: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /Users/minhthuanluu/Documents/ViettelTelemor/Web/boc2_web/jsf-api-2.2.0.jar
no main manifest attribute, in /Users/minhthuanluu/Documents/ViettelTelemor/Web/boc2_web/jsf-api-2.2.0.jar

There is the error when I run the project. Because jsf-api-2.2.0.jar is a .jar file. I cannot update it. Did you meet these error before?

Comment: You may want to include the `pom.xml` in your question above. Also, search the web for potential answers for this error message you are seeing: "jsf-api-2.2.0.jar no main manifest attribute,"

Comment: Guys, OP is basically trying to execute it as a plain Java/JAR project instead of as a Servlet/WAR project. A WAR has indeed no main manifest at all (as that's basically on the server itself). OP just needs to take a step back and learn how to create a Servlet based hello world project from scratch in order to understand the core principles.